# TimeoutError when two computers communicated

Tags: python, linux

I am using Python3 to learn distributed programming

there are two python file，one's name is main.py, it distributes information, the other one manipulation data, and the name is worker.py.

everything goes well when I run this two file in one computer[set server address = 127.0.0.1, port = 5000]

but when i run these two files in seperate computers, they cannot connect to each other, and TimeoutError was encoutered.

I don't know why. one computer is Win10 at my home, the other is a linux cloud server which I baught.

the code works in one computer. but when I ran main.py in linux, and ran worker.py{change server to linux's ip address} in win10, then the worker.py encounter a TimeoutError

I know nothing about the linux, is there some security settings I need to open or close?

```
"""main.py"""

import queue
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import datetime
import time

TASK_QUEUE = queue.Queue()
RESULT_QUEUE = queue.Queue()

def get_task_queue():
    """set TASK_QUEUE as a function"""
    global TASK_QUEUE
    return TASK_QUEUE


def receive_result_queue():
    """set RESULT_QUEUE as a function"""
    global RESULT_QUEUE
    return RESULT_QUEUE


class QueueManager(BaseManager):
    """inherit BaseManager from multiprocessing.managers"""
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    QueueManager.register('distribute_task_queue', callable=get_task_queue)
    QueueManager.register('receive_result_queue', callable=receive_result_queue)

    # bind port 5000, set verification code = 'abc'
    MANAGER = QueueManager(address=('127.0.0.1', 5000), authkey=b'abc')

    # start manager
    MANAGER.start()

    TASK = MANAGER.distribute_task_queue()
    RESULT = MANAGER.receive_result_queue()

    # put each line into manager`enter code here`
    with open("C:/Users/dayia/Desktop/log.20170817") as f:
        for line in f:
            TASK.put(line)

    # try receive result
    while 1:
        try:
            r = RESULT.get(timeout=1)
            if r[0] == r[1] and r[0] == "done":
                break
            else:
                print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),"line %s\'s length is %s" % (r[0], r[1]))
        except queue.Empty:
            print('result queue is empty.')
```

#

```
"""worker.py"""

import datetime
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import queue
import time


class QueueManager(BaseManager):
    """inherit BaseManager from multiprocessing.managers"""
    pass


QueueManager.register('distribute_task_queue')
QueueManager.register('receive_result_queue')

server_addr = '127.0.0.1'
print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 'Connect to server %s...' % server_addr)
m = QueueManager(address=(server_addr, 5000), authkey=b'abc')

m.connect()

TASK = m.distribute_task_queue()
RESULT = m.receive_result_queue()

def parse_line(line):
    return len(line)

C = 0

while not TASK.empty():
    try:
        n = TASK.get(timeout=1)
        r = parse_line(n)
        print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 'running line %s, length is %s' % (C+1, r))
        C += 1
        RESULT.put([r, C])
    except queue.Empty:
        print('task queue is empty.')

RESULT.put(["done", "done"])
enter code here
print('worker exit')
```

Comment: Please post some of your code to help understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address `127.0.0.1` very specifically refers to the same computer where the code is running (in network terms: `127.0.0.1` is the IP address of `localhost`) .

Comment: in my case, i know the server address in worker.py has to be setted as linux's ip(where main.py run), but how to set the  server address in main.py

Comment: Change `server_addr = '127.0.0.1'` to the correct IP address, or make the script accept a configurable parameter via a command-line option or configuration file.  In the server, you probably want to listen to `0.0.0.0` to accept connections from anywhere.

Comment: I did as you said, in worker.py, set server_addr to the correct IP, and in server,listen to 0.0.0.0, but still worker.py encounter error "TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]", main.py keep waitting worker.py's result

Comment: Then it's not a programming problem. Do you have a firewall in between? Can you ping the external network from both computers? Can the hosts ping each other? Try to reduce this to a [mcve]

Comment: yes, hosts can ping each other, but I am not sure about the firewall part.

Comment: Can you connect with `telnet` to the server and port from the client?

Comment: no , I can't.   telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Resource temporarily unavailable

Comment: how to fix it? I don't know much about linux. Can you tell me which part of linux need to set correctly, I'll google it

Comment: There are far too many things which could be wrong, something like https://superuser.com/questions/607005/ping-works-but-not-telnet-in-putty

Comment: OK，thank you very much. I google it  for a while, and it seems a very complicate problem. my linux server is almost a new server and nothing is in it. I descide to stop google it, and try this code on two windows computer

Comment: Actually, it's probably fairly simple, but this space is much too small to go through the various scenarios and it's not a programming topic anyway, so not suitable for Stack Overflow.  Try our sister sites [su] or [sf] but search before asking -- they probably already have quite good answers to this common FAQ.